# golang/sqlserver positional parameters in select statements

Tags: sql-server, go

Can anyone provide a working example of a Query or QueryRow (not QueryContext) with a simple select and 2 (or more) positional parameters using the golang sqlserver driver?

There's some churn, apparently: https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb/issues/260

The only sample code given is for QueryContext which is hypercomplex for a simple cli data transition program. This is brain-dead simple with postgres or mysql but I'm dead in the water with sql server.

Using:

```
var checkQuery = "select SigCode from @LRU where LRUEmu=@ENVVAR"
...
rows, err := db.Query(checkQuery, sql.Named("LRU", string1), sql.Named("ENVVAR", string2))
```

yields:

`application() rows.Query() failed:mssql: Must declare the table variable "@LRU".`

Edit. Per @Flimzy below, retried with QueryContext:

`rows, err := db.QueryContext(context.TODO(), checkQuery,sql.Named("LRU", string1), sql.Named("ENVVAR", string2))`

Same error.

@MWillemse: Here is some sample code (pymssql) which uses a variable to specify the target table:

```
slice_cursor.execute(
    "select distinct Subsystem, Field from [%(dlog)s] "
    "where Subsystem not like 'STRING1' "
    "order by Subsystem, Field"
    % {
        'dlog' : datelog
    }
)
```

I do it all the time. In golang/pg as well, works like a charm.

@putu: I tried your suggestion but no joy. New error, though...

```
var checkQuery = "DECLARE @LRU VARCHAR(255), @ENVVAR VARCHAR(255); select SigCode from @LRU where LRUEmu=@ENVVAR;"

// ...

rows, err := db.Query(checkQuery, sql.Named("LRU", string1), sql.Named("ENVVAR", string2))
```

Yields:

`mssql: The variable name '@LRU' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.`

Comment: If string1 contains a table name it seems to me you need put the table name in the string before passing it to Sql Server. Sql server has let you know it was given a string where it expected a table variable. It is talking about @LRU you've put in the FROM clause of your query.

Comment: `QueryContext` is not hyper complex at all. It only takes one additional argument, and it can be effectively ignored by using `context.TODO()`.

Comment: @MWillemse - see the meager documentation for this at

https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb

Comment: @Flimzy - heh - I thought that TODO line was a typo in the Go docs ;-). Tried it with QueryContext, still the same error as posted above.

Comment: How if you change the query to `var checkQuery = "DECLARE @LRU VARCHAR(255), @ENVVAR VARCHAR(255); select SigCode from @LRU where LRUEmu=@ENVVAR;"`?

Comment: @putu: recall that these queries are being assembled in source code. In your example above, where does one enter the variable values?

Comment: The variable value is assigned when you call the `db.Query`, i.e. `db.Query(checkQuery, sql.Named("LRU", string1), sql.Named("ENVVAR", string2))`

Comment: @putu thanks - tried it but no joy - see my edit above...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know golang but i do know sql server.

```
var checkQuery = "select SigCode from @LRU where LRUEmu=@ENVVAR"
rows, err := db.Query(checkQuery, sql.Named("LRU", string1), sql.Named("ENVVAR", string2))
```

These lines must be getting translated into SQL code and send to SQL server. The resulting SQL code probably looks something like this:

```
DECLARE @LRU   NVARCHAR(MAX) = '<contents of string 1>';
DECLARE @ENVAR NVARCHAR(MAX) = '<contents of string 2>';
select SigCode from @LRU where LRUEmu=@ENVVAR
```

When this is executed SQL Server will raise the error

```
Must declare the table variable "@LRU"
```

Which is caught and rethrown by your QueryContext.

The reason for SQL server to raise the error is an syntax error in the query. SQL server does not (and afaik neither do other rdbms) allow you to put table names in a variable and run a select against it.

So you either to this:

```
var checkQuery = "select SigCode from " + string1 + " where LRUEmu=@ENVVAR"
rows, err := db.Query(checkQuery, sql.Named("ENVVAR", string2))
```

or use dynamic sql like this:

```
var checkQuery = 
       "DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
           'select SigCode from '+@LRU+' where LRUEmu=@ENVVAR';
        EXEC(@SQL);"
rows, err := db.Query(checkQuery, sql.Named("LRU", string1), sql.Named("ENVVAR", string2))
```

Comment: I use variables as tables names all the time. See my edit above for  a python sample in production code which uses pymssql.

Comment: Also, I tried your very last last code suggestion above and '+' signs generate run-time errors, and without them I get the usual LRU undefined errors. The plus sign errors are probably driver issues, I've used that syntax before in SQLS Mgmt Studio...

Comment: That variable is resolved by the phython code before sending it off to the sql server. About the + sign, I assumed you'd know how to concatenate 3 strings together which I (again) assumed you'd understand was the purpose of that line of code. Anyway, please reread my awnser and try to understand what I'm saying about what is happing where when you execute those 2 lines of code. If possible start a debug session and step into db.Query method to see what it does with your query before sending it off to SQL Server.

Comment: I can do it using plus signs but there's no real way to let the db driver sanitize the inputs that way.  By using  parametric insertion both the compiler and the db driver help to sanitize the inputs. I stopped assembling SQL strings in that manner 3 years (and 2 languages) ago. Simple brute force string assembly is not the way to go imo. If you look at the way this is done with other RDMBS drivers in python/perl/go parametric insertion is the way to go.

And yes, I missed the plus signs. Sorry, pre-coffee.

Comment: Again - this all works like a charm in python. I will stick with p3 for now and see if I can help with the go driver in some way. Ironically I was trying to use this little project as a way to introduce golang into our dev org...